# How to add 2 columns in Power BI measures using filters on min date?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like this :

```
Id  numbers_old  numbers_new  date
1    5              0         2019-02-13
1    8              3         2019-02-14
2    2              0         2019-02-13
2    12             10        2019-02-14
2    15             5         2019-02-15
```

I want a measure which will calculate `volume_total = (number_old where date=min(date)) + (numbers_new where date != min(date))`

How can I achieve it with a Power BI measure?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the measure:

```
volume_total = 
VAR DateMin = 
    MIN ( Table1[date] )
VAR SumOld = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Table1[numbers_old] ),
        Table1[date] = DateMin
    )
VAR SumNew = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Table1[numbers_new] ),
        Table1[date] <> DateMin
    )
RETURN
    SumOld + SumNew
```

Worked example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_54707672/